# C code crashes when running strcpy() for the second time

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf, strcpy

I have a struct that looks like the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    char matrikelnr[10];
    double note;
} Hashtable_Entry_t;
```

And then I try to fill the struct in the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Hashtable_Entry_t* student;
    strcpy(student->matrikelnr, "70468878");
    student->note = 1.0;
    printf("%s, %.1f \n", student->matrikelnr, student->note);

    Hashtable_Entry_t* student2;
    printf("Before 2nd strcpy.\n");
    strcpy(student2->matrikelnr, "70468878");
    printf("Before 2nd strcpy.\n");
    student2->note = 1.0;
    printf("%s, %.f", student2->matrikelnr, student2->note);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And when I then take a look at the output I see that the printf() after the second strcpy() wont run and the code just stops:

```
70468878, 1.0
Before 2nd strcpy.
```

So can someone tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You must allocate space for `student` variable before using it.

Comment: Or declare and use a `Hashtable_Entry_t` directly, instead of going through a pointer to one.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Fix them as you get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
Hashtable_Entry_t* student;
Hashtable_Entry_t* student2;
```

`student` and `student2` are **uninitalised** pointer. If you not initialize them then they will point to some random memory address.

Instead of using pointer you can directly use the variable of `Hashtable_Entry_t` type.

```c
Hashtable_Entry_t student;
strcpy(student.matrikelnr, "70468878");
student.note = 1.0;
printf("%s, %.1f \n", student.matrikelnr, student.note);
```

If you really wants to use pointer, then you can initialize them in the following ways:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>  // for malloc

Hashtable_Entry_t* student = malloc(sizeof(Hashtable_Entry_t));
strcpy(student->matrikelnr, "70468878");
student->note = 1.0;
printf("%s, %.1f \n", student->matrikelnr, student->note);

// Assign address of Hashtable_Entry_t variable
Hashtable_Entry_t student;
Hashtable_Entry_t* student_ptr = &student;
strcpy(student_ptr->matrikelnr, "70468878");
student_ptr->note = 1.0;
```

Comment: `#include <stdlib.c>` is surely wrong. Aside: [do not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965) in C.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated my answer but for malloc I did cross verify [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), it did come from `stdlib.c`.

Comment: @Aamir Read it again, *Defined in header `<stdlib.h>`* is emblazoned immediately above the prototype. There is no `stdlib.c` formally defined in the standard library, nor does it appear anywhere on that page. It is called `stdlib.h` , a *header* file that declares a multitude of things, `malloc` being one of them.

Comment: Ohh… for some strange reasons, my eyes refuse to recognize the typo error. I intended to mention `.h` not `.c`.  Thanks for bringing it into attention. Corrected the typo.